# Error message: Error in `vec_as_location()`: ! `...` must be empty

Tags: r

This is for a homework assignment: I am trying to use the group_by function to group a column by species and then I would like to find the mean height of each species. Here was my code, which was suggested to me by some of the homework materials.

Code:

```
dataframe.long<-dataframe.long%>%
  group_by(species)%>%
  mutate(height_averages = mean(plant_height))
```

The error code in the console reads as follows:

```
> dataframe.long<-dataframe.long%>%
+   group_by(species)%>%
+   mutate(height_averages = mean(plant_height))
Error in `vec_as_location()`:
! `...` must be empty.
x Problematic argument:
* call = call
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlib_error_dots_nonempty>
Error in `vec_as_location()`:
! `...` must be empty.
x Problematic argument:
* call = call
---
Backtrace:
  1. dataframe.long %>% group_by(species) %>% ...
  4. dplyr:::group_by.data.frame(., species)
  5. dplyr::grouped_df(groups$data, groups$group_names, .drop)
  6. dplyr:::compute_groups(data, vars, drop = drop)
  8. tibble:::`[.tbl_df`(as_tibble(data), vars)
  9. tibble:::vectbl_as_col_location(...)
 12. vctrs::vec_as_location(j, n, names, call = call)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

Running 'rlang::last_trace gives this

```
---
Backtrace:
     x
  1. +-dataframe.long %>% group_by(species) %>% ...
  2. +-dplyr::mutate(., height_averages = mean(plant_height))
  3. +-dplyr::group_by(., species)
  4. \-dplyr:::group_by.data.frame(., species)
  5.   \-dplyr::grouped_df(groups$data, groups$group_names, .drop)
  6.     \-dplyr:::compute_groups(data, vars, drop = drop)
  7.       +-as_tibble(data)[vars]
  8.       \-tibble:::`[.tbl_df`(as_tibble(data), vars)
  9.         \-tibble:::vectbl_as_col_location(...)
 10.           +-tibble:::subclass_col_index_errors(...)
 11.           | \-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 12.           \-vctrs::vec_as_location(j, n, names, call = call)
 13.             \-ellipsis::check_dots_empty()
 14.               \-rlang:::action_dots(...)
 15.                 +-base (local) try_dots(...)
 16.                 \-rlang (local) action(...)
```

Here is a glimpse of my data frame

```
Rows: 40
Columns: 7
$ date         <chr> "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/20~
$ plant_ID     <chr> "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "21", "22", "23", "24"~
$ observer     <chr> "EBG", "EBG", "EBG", "EBG", "EBG", "EBG", "EBG", "EBG", "EBG", "EBG", "JF~
$ herbivory    <chr> "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", NA, NA, "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", NA, "~
$ notes        <chr> "", "", "", "", "", "", "Plant dead ", "Plant missing ", "", "", "", "", ~
$ species      <chr> "deba", "deba", "deba", "deba", "deba", "deba", "deba", "deba", "deba", "~
$ plant_height <dbl> 45.5, 23.5, 36.0, 24.5, 23.1, 21.5, 0.0, 0.0, 33.5, 33.7, 15.8, 20.4, 8.6~
```

Please let me know if you have any other solutions! TYIA!

What have I done to try to mitigate this:
-restarted R, my computer, updated all packages and R in general, tried summarise instead of mutate

I thought that this function would create a new column in my dataframe that had a new column labelled height_averages but instead I got the error message above

here is the result from dput function:

```
structure(list(date = c("5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", 
"5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", 
"5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", 
"5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", 
"5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", 
"5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", 
"5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", 
"5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", "5/22/2022", 
"5/22/2022", "5/22/2022"), plant_ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
"19", "20", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", 
"39", "40"), observer = c("EBG", "EBG", "EBG", "EBG", "EBG", 
"EBG", "EBG", "EBG", "EBG", "EBG", "JF", "JF", "JF", "JF", "JF", 
"JF", "JF", "JF", "JF", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", 
"KA", "KA", "KA", "CM", "CM", "CM", "CM", "CM", "CM", "CM", "CM", 
"CM", "CM", "CM"), herbivory = c("N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", 
NA, NA, "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", NA, "Y", "Y", "Y", NA, 
"N", "N", NA, "Y", "Y", "N", NA, "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", NA, 
"Y", "N", "N", "Y", NA, "Y", "Y", "N"), notes = c("", "", "", 
"", "", "", "Plant dead ", "Plant missing ", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "Plant missing ", "", "", "", "Plant Dead", "", "", "Plant missingÂ ", 
"", "", "", "Plant dead", "", "", "", "", "", "Plant missing", 
"", "", "", "", "Plant dead", "", "", ""), species = c("deba", 
"deba", "deba", "deba", "deba", "deba", "deba", "deba", "deba", 
"deba", "denu", "denu", "denu", "denu", "denu", "denu", "denu", 
"denu", "denu", "getr", "getr", "getr", "getr", "getr", "getr", 
"getr", "getr", "getr", "getr", "lile", "lile", "lile", "lile", 
"lile", "lile", "lile", "lile", "lile", "lile", "lile"), plant_height = c(45.5, 
23.5, 36, 24.5, 23.1, 21.5, 0, 0, 33.5, 33.7, 15.8, 20.4, 8.6, 
18.9, 0, 16.9, 15.2, 32.1, 0, 6.2, 7.4, 0, 1.1, 2.2, 3.1, 0, 
6.4, 4.1, 2.2, 41.8, 33.6, 0, 32.4, 37.3, 37.5, 11.9, 0, 46.3, 
37.9, 41.6)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It looks like [others who’ve had this issue](https://www.google.com/search?q=%60vec_as_location()%60:+!+%60...%60+must+be+empty+site:community.rstudio.com&client=safari&hl=en-us&prmd=visn&sxsrf=AJOqlzUbMkPTv8t0yeC-gyduXz-xusUm-A:1673142438750&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZoOGl7bb8AhWYrYkEHVotAZkQrQIoAnoECBEQAw&biw=375&bih=710&dpr=3) have had luck with re-installing vctrs via `install.packages("vctrs")`, even if `update.packages()` didn’t work. You might give that a try.

Comment: @zephryl I added the results of dput to the question, thank you so much! allow me to check out the install.packages("vctrs")

Comment: @zephryl the solution of install.packages("vctrs") worked for me!! Thank you so much!!!! I have been trying to figure this out for at least 3 hours now. You are a scholar.

Comment: @zephryl Thanks. That fixed my situation perfectly.